# Skip the revert dialog

Tags: dialog-window

When saving a file and making changes to it one can revert using `File->Revert` in the menu or by entering

`FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Revert"]]`

before reverting a dialog window opens to ask if you are sure. I would like to skip this dialog by automatically answering with yes.

Is that possible?

**Edit:**

Here is a picture of the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `False` as a second argument to `FrontEndToken` for "Revert":

`FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Revert", False]]`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!